# json asp.net webservice call error

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-services, json

I am trying to post some info with an ajax request to a webservice I wrote with some json data

Here are the C# parameters the method receiving it uses

```
public bool AdvancedIWant(string WantTitle, 
int WantCategory, 
string WantBlogID, 
float WantPrice, 
string WantComments)
```

When I go to the asmx control directly and enter in the values it works fine so it is something with my json format I am guessing...
I used firebug to look at the ajax headers and I got this under post

> JSON   WantComments   "sdfa" Source
>   {"WantTitle": "sdfs"},
>   {"WantCategory": 1}, {"WantBlog":
>   "FCA184D9-9F50-473F-922D-04E0EE004AB8"},
>   {"WantPrice": 5.55}, {"WantComments":
>   "sdfa"}

this under response

> {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: 
>   {\"WantCategory\": 1}, {\"WantBlog\":
>   \"FCA184D9-9F50-473F-922D-04E0EE004AB8\"},
>   {\"WantPrice\": 5.55},
>   {\"WantComments\":
>   \"sdfa\"}.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String
>   input, Int32 depthLimit,
>   JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type,
>   Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext
>   context, JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

I am guessin my json format is invalid?? I'm not sure maybe I am just missing something at 2 am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your post to server be like this:

```
{"WantTitle": "sdfs", "WantCategory": 1, "WantBlog": "FCA184D9-9F50-473F-922D-04E0EE004AB8", "WantPrice": 5.55, "WantComments": "sdfa"}
```

Compare above with your JSON. I feel you have constructed your JSON in wrong format.

Further watch out for `WantBlog`, in service your parameter says `WantBlogId`.

Comment: that totally fixed it thank you very much! I can sleep now :D